# Error while installing react-native-vcard package

Tags: android, react-native, npm-install, vcf-vcard

I am trying to install 'React Native vCards' plugin for my react-native application. But when I run

`npm install react-native-vcards@https://github.com/idxbroker/react-native-vcards.git --save`

I am getting following errors

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t 
https://github.com/idxbroker/react-native-vcards.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! remote: Invalid username or password.
npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for 
'https://github.com/idxbroker/react-native-vcards.git/'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dijish/.npm/_logs/2018-09-02T10_18_24_987Z- 
debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this command

`npm install react-native-vcards@https://github.com/idxbroker/react-native-vcards.git --save`

Add `"vcards-js": "git+https://git@github.com/idxbroker/vCards-js#react-native"` to package.json dependencies

and run `npm install`

and use this plugin as `import vCard from 'vcards-js';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
npm install react-native-vcards@https://github.com/hammadj/react-native-vcards --save
```